# Scikit-Learn Not Properly Updating in IPython

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ipython, rollback, scikit-learn

I am attempting to update scikit-learn within IPython to version 0.14 from 0.13 using the following command in the IPython shell:

```
!pip install scikit-learn --update
```

Everything appears to be updating, but when I look at the pip log I see the below (I would appreciate any insight):

```
 Rolling back uninstall of scikit-learn

  Replacing c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.13-py2.7.egg-info
Command C:\Anaconda\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\owner\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build\\scikit-learn\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\owner\appdata\local\temp\pip-pqca_z-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\temp\pip-build\scikit-learn

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 107, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 261, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1166, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 589, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 612, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command C:\Anaconda\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\owner\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build\\scikit-learn\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\owner\appdata\local\temp\pip-pqca_z-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\temp\pip-build\scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using anaconda so you should use the conda commandline (`conda update scikit-learn`) to update Anaconda packages instead of pip.